# Unable to implement Impulse MF in Fuzzy Logic Toolbox,

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

I'm trying to implement Impulse MF in Fuzzy Logic Toolbox in Matlab as shown in Fig.1
 Link : http://s17.postimg.org/bbhkcibbj/fig_1.png

But when am trying to implement in matlab am unable to do so. As shown in figure 2

Link to Fig 2.  http://s17.postimg.org/cf6a27lcf/fig_2.png

How can i do it in matlab.

Comment: Please show your code! We can't guess what you tried.

Comment: @Benoit_11 am trying it in Fuzzy Logic Toolbox, details are in figure 2.